# How can I build iOS app with titles like ViewPager with ViewPagerIndicator in Android? (exactly like android playstore)

Tags: android, ios, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

i found same question in here, but answer is not what exactly i required. anyone please help me to build ios app with pageview like what exactly done in new android playstore. 
thanks in advance .

UPDATE: 
i found some solutions , but cannot satisfied with them, so i just changed my design plan. anyone please suggest me to achieve same but with different stylish layouts something like menu button with title.

Comment: i want to implement this to ios, not android. is it possible to use pagertabstrip in ios ..?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.  Doh.

Comment: Try use PageViewController - there is a lot of examples in google and I think you will have possibility to create from PVC something like ViewPager

Comment: thanks for your comment, i just changed my question, please read that

Comment: It's unfair your question was downvoted, i'm also facing same situation, doing research and will keep you posted...